# Rewrite NGINX URL Location?

Tags: php, html, redirect, nginx, https

I want to use Baikal on my server together with NGINX. The index.php of baikal is in /baikal/html

The request for the following configuration works with this url:

```
https://www.mydomain.com:8001/baikal/html
```

How can I change the NGINX configuration that

```
https://www.mydomain.com:8001/baikal
```

gets redirected to https://www.mydomain.com:8001/baikal/html?

Here is my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
        listen 8001;

        ssl on; # <-------------------------------------------- SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/seahub.crt; # <--------- SSL
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/seahub.key; # <----- SSL

        server_name confile.no-ip.biz; #.tld; # <----------------- CHANGE THIS

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /cal.php redirect;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /card.php redirect;

        location / {


        location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*) {
                try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        charset utf-8;

        location ~ /(\.ht|Core|Specific) {
                deny all;
                return 404;
        }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not have a `location` inside of another `location`. Make sure they're all seperate.

Next, to actually create the rewrite:

```
location = /baikal {
  return 301 /baikal/html
}
```

should do the trick.